# OpenVPN + UFW OVERKILL

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ufw

I am using [instructions found on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039034/is-vpn-ufw-as-a-killswitch-broken-in-18-04) to configure my UFW to act as a "killswitch" for a potential dropped openvpn connection.  My ufw rules are as follows:

```
sudo bash -c "ufw -f reset && iptables -F && iptables -X \
&& sudo ufw default deny incoming && sudo ufw default deny outgoing \
&& sudo ufw allow ssh && sudo ufw allow out on <device 1> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 1> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 2> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 3> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 4> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 1> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 2> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 3> from any to <vpn ip> \
&& sudo ufw allow out on <device 4> from any to any && sudo ufw enable"
```

[image]

The Problem is that when I `sudo ufw enable`..... ALL CONNECTIONS are dead and I have ZERO internet connectivity, hence "overkill" :-)

Solutions That I Have Tried:

1. Thoroughly, disabled IPv6 on all connections and through sysctl
2. Flushed iptables (see above script)
3. Reloaded the system-daemon, using `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Tried stop | start | reload openvpn service, using `sudo service openvpn reload`

**suspected problem**
I *think* the problem -may- be caused by DNS service (duckdns) not updating my public IP because I similar output from `sudo service openvpn status` [as found in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114160/ubuntu-18-04-openvpn-not-starting-status-active-exited), which actually posts "answer" without the actual steps to solve the problem (completely not useful). Therefore I could be absolutely wrong.

FYI, if I reboot with UFW disabled, it connects to vpn, without problem. only enabling UFW kills everything.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you making sure you are activating ufw rules _after_ you connect to your VPN? Are you sure you are replacing <device> with the actual interface the VPN connection creates? They may be called differently depending on what software you use. Also, you might have to add an incoming rule from the VPN server to your machine for it to work. I use iptables directly for that, but that's what I'm doing.

Comment: I configured openvpn with sysctl to connect on boot and I have an extension that confirms my connection in the panel bar (I'm sure ;-)  I, personally added the <device #> and <vpn ip > tags as to keep the real information secret, so the real script is what I am working with.  Incoming rule for VPN, I don't know about that... did you check the post that I linked to?

Comment: Yes, I figured you replaced the <device> placeholder, the question was more if it was with the correct device names. Different VPN providers may create different names. And yes I read the referred post, but at some point I switched from ufw to using iptables directly because it worked more reliably. Don't know about the DNS thing, but I never had to do anything about that. Do you even use duckdns?